# OpenLDAP - Programmatically update slapd configuration

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, openldap

I'm using [slapd-mdb](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman5/slapd-mdb.5.html) and I'm looking for a way to programmatically update "maxsize" parameter using ldapmodify or similar: http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman5/slapd-mdb.5.html

My main problem is that I have a huge dataset and I need more space.

Any suggestions on how to update OpenLDAP configuration programmatically would be appreciated.

My environment is Kubernetes and I deployed OpenLDAP as a container.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `slapd.conf` if you want online updating. See the documentation. Off topic

Comment: @user207421 thanks, do you know how to perform online updating ?

Comment: @user207421 can you please share your findings? I couldn’t find anything related in documentation. I know there is a way by modifying cn=config but I couldn’t find an exact solution for slapd-mdb

Comment: You could not find it where? It's is all right there in the documentation. Not Google. The Documentation. Look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Quickstart"](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) section of the OpenLDAP documentation includes a mdb sample configuration:

```
dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config 
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig 
objectClass: olcMdbConfig 
olcDatabase: mdb 
OlcDbMaxSize: 1073741824 
olcSuffix: dc=<MY-DOMAIN>,dc=<COM> 
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=<MY-DOMAIN>,dc=<COM> 
olcRootPW: secret 
olcDbDirectory: /usr/local/var/openldap-data 
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
```

- Replace the placeholders in `olcSuffix`, `olcRootDN` and `olcRootPW`  with your values, change the `OlcDbMaxSize` value to suit your requirement.
- Import your configration database:

```
su root -c /usr/local/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F /usr/local/etc/slapd.d -l /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif
```

- Start SLAPD:

```
su root -c /usr/local/libexec/slapd -F /usr/local/etc/slapd.d
```